# Отступ внутри блока относительно элемента

Tags: css, html, margin

Помогите сделать `margin` внутри блока.

Есть `div` и 5 элементов `li` (в одну линию) из которых по два крайних надо поставить ниже, так, чтобы средний элемент остался на месте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если подходит вариант с flex, то так:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  transform: translateY(100%)
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(0);
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYNGKW

Comment: Мда.. Вот, оказывается, что имелось в виду в вопросе... Впрочем, flex тут совсем необязательно.

Comment: да, ну тогда нужно с margin'ами возится

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  width: 33.333333%;
  height: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(-10deg, blue, red);
}
```

```html
<ul><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 4px dotted green;
}

li {
  width: 33.333333%;
  height: 3em;
  float: left;
  background: linear-gradient(-10deg, blue, red);
}

li:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
```